# Function from other module not detecting

Tags: erlang, intellisense

I two modules in same src folder. mod1 declares function I wish to use in module mod2:

```
-module(mod1).
-export([myfunc/1]).

myfunc(A) -> {ok}.
```

In other module I not import mod1:

```
-module(mod2).
```

If I do "`mod1:`" in mod2 it recognizes "myfunc", problem is at run-time when I call `mod1:myfunc(A)` I get "undefined function mod1:myfunc/1"

I not understand why I get error if intellisense detect my mod1 function in mod2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the shell, you could try doing `mod1:module_info(exports)` to see the list of all the exported functions, though if your module is written as it is above, it should be generating a syntax error.

If, however, I'm wrong, and you actually do have it written properly in your module, (ie, it's just a typo here), try doing the following at the erlang shell:

```
c(mod1).
c(mod2).
```

And see if that works for you.  This will compile and load the modules for you.  If you don't have the module compiled (ie, it's just a .erl file in the directory), that's insufficient.

**EDIT**

Also, make sure that the beam files are being loaded properly when erlang launches.  This is typically done by launching erl with `erl -pa /path/to/beams`

Comment: Sorry i have it written correctly, i typed it on this question wrong. Both modules compile fine

Comment: Roger that. I've removed the reference to the syntax error from my answer. What happens if you type `mod1:module_info(exports)` from your erlang shell?

Comment: Further, I've edited my answer to include another recommendation to ensure your modules are being loaded properly.

Comment: Ok figured it- it is cos i not compile. I was copy and paste my compile commands but didn't include mod1. So when I close terminal and  paste my commands, mod1 was not compiled each time. Tahnk you!